# Understanding Scope on Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm understanding "Scope" I found this code, but Im wondering how
can I execute the "inner" function, I tried like this:

*outer().inner();*

but doesn't works

```
        /* global scope */
        var local = true;
        var global = true;
        function outer() {
            /* local scope */
            var local = true;
            var global = false;

            /* nearest scope = outer */
            local = !global;
            console.log("Local: "+local);
            console.log("Global: "+Global);

            function inner() {
                /* nearest scope = outer */
                local = false;
                global = false;

                /* nearest scope = undefined */
                /* defaults to defining a global */
                public = global;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can modify the outer function to add a statement to return the inner function "return inner;"  and then you could call the inner function as          var inner = outer(); inner();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `outer` to be an object instead of a function.

```
/* global scope */
var local = true;
var global = true;
var outer = {
    /* local scope */
    local : true,
    global : false,

    /* nearest scope = outer */
    local : !global,

    showLogs: function(){
        console.log("Local: "+local);
        console.log("Global: "+Global);
    },

    inner: function(){
        local = false;
        global = false;
        public = global;
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm declaring outer as an object instead of a function with `var outer={}` That way you can call the functions with `outer.inner();` and `outer.showLogs();`

Comment: Great Thanks! On comment I think I must put commas instead of semicolons :D !

Comment: Whoops! You're absolutely right. I just edited it to show commas.

Answer (score 1):

While inside `outer`, you can simply call `inner()`. It is defined inside `outer` and can't be called outside of `outer` as is. However, you can set `outer` to return 'inner'. @jthomas shows a couple examples of this below.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access `inner()`, `outer()` would need to return `inner()`.

Example:

```
function outer() {
  ...

  return {
     inner: function inner() {
       ...
     }
  };
}

outer().inner();
```

Another kind of interesting thing that's possible:

```
function outer() {
  return function inner() {}
}

outer()();
```

Comment: Oh Very interesting! The Second one is like an "Anonymous function" inside a function right?

Comment: Yeah, you don't really need to name that inner function. I just included that for illustration's sake. `return function() { }` would have worked the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. You can make the inner function a method if you want and call that... like so:

http://output.jsbin.com/wuseqonuxa/2/edit?js,console (You will get the console logging "Im running").

```js
/* global scope */
var local = true;
var global = true;

function outer() {
    /* local scope */
    var local = true;
    var global = false;
    
    /* nearest scope = outer */
    local = !global;
    console.log("Local: "+local);
    console.log("Global: "+global);
    
    this.inner = function () {
        /* nearest scope = outer */
        local = false;
        global = false;
        
        /* nearest scope = undefined */
        /* defaults to defining a global */
        public = global;
        console.log('Im running');
    }
}

var outer = new outer();
outer.inner();
```

Comment: Is like if inner is a method now?
 I mean outer is now an Object and inner is a method ?

Answer (score 0):

The inner function can only be accessed by code within `outer`. Code outside of `outer` cannot access `inner`.